# Save url clicked as a session

Tags: php

Using php i quay links from a database. when the link is clicked it should take me to a page. the problem here is the pages content depends on what link is clicked. i am trying to make a page were you can score stuff. the scores are in one database and the links are in another. is there

> A:
>   a way to just add one number up from the last number in the database. for example the databases number is 1 and i click a button it will then be 2.
>
> B:
>   is there a way to add a session with the link which is clicked and then somehow quay the name of the table that the scores are in.

i think A would be easier but i can not find an answer for this anywhere. my code is a mess and having the numbers just add up would be easier. i am here to answer any questions because im not very good at explaining things.

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "score";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM all_scores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<p></p>";
             echo "<a href=add/all_games/".$row['id']."/viewlink.php>". $row["name"]. "</a>";
                 echo "<p>". $row["description"]. "</p>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (depending on what the `id` equals, different content will be echoed):

**Page with the links**

```
<a href="location.php?id=1>Example</a>
<a href="location.php?id=2>Example</a>
<a href="location.php?id=3>Example</a>
```

**Location.php**

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) === false) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id == 1){
echo 'Content displayed from clicking the first link';
}

if ($id == 2){
echo 'Content displayed from clicking the second link';
}

if ($id == 3){
echo 'Content displayed from clicking the third link';
}

}
```